# Docker bind mount volumes do not propagate changes events watched by angular `ng serve` execution

Tags: angular, docker, angular-cli, dockerfile, mounted-volumes

**Following these steps:**

1. Define the Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM node:alpine

   RUN yarn global add @angular/cli
   RUN yarn global add node-sass

   RUN mkdir /volumes

   WORKDIR /volumes

   EXPOSE 4200

   ENTRYPOINT ["ng"]
   ```
2. Build an image from this Dockerfile:

   ```
   docker build -t my_angular_image .
   ```
3. Use the image to create a new angular app :

   ```
   // Create the new app
   docker run --rm --mount type=bind,src=$PWD,dst=/volumes my_angular_image new my-app --directory app --style scss
   // Change ownership of the generated app
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .
   ```
4. Based on the image, run a container bind mounting the app volume:

   ```
   docker run -p 4200:4200 --mount type=bind,src=$PWD/app,dst=/volumes my_angular_image serve --host 0.0.0.0
   ```

**Results:**
The first compilation works as expected and the container serves the app. However, when changing the value (from host) of a file which has to be watched by `ng serve` in container, a new angular build is not triggered (and so, the served app is not updated).

**Question:**
Does someone know why changing the value of a bind mount volume on host does not trigger the angular `ng serve` update in container (as it does when not using Docker)?

**Environment:**

- OS : Ubuntu 16.04
- Docker : 18.01.0-ce

Comment: Which OS are you running docker on?

Comment: Yes, this will not work on a Windows docker host with a Linux container.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added an environment section, I am on Ubuntu Xenial.

Comment: @Brian even if I am not on a Windows docker host, I am curious, can you explain why this will not work on a Windows docker host with a Linux container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make the example working, replace step 3 by the commands below:

```
// Create the new app
docker run --rm --mount type=bind,src=$PWD,dst=/volumes my_angular_image new my-app --directory app --style scss
// Change ownership of the generated app
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .
// Configure angular-cli polling:
sed -i 's/\"styleExt\": \"scss\",/"styleExt": "scss", "poll": 1000,/g' $PWD/app/.angular-cli.json
```

**Credits:**

- @PavelAgarkov's answer and its usefull links.

Answer (score 3):

there is a hidden option for angular-cli.json named `poll` by specifying which you can change the way how underlining webpack watches for file updates.
Links:

1. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions-poll
2. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1814
3. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli#angular-cli-config-schema